# php date format giving wrong output

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to send a date value to an xml rpc web service from my php page.

following is the code I am using

```
$LicenseData->LicenseDate  = "2014.05.06 00:00:00";
if (strlen($LicenseData->LicenseDate) > 0) {

  $arDate = explode(".", $LicenseData->LicenseDate);
  $arDate[0] = intval($arDate[0]);
  $arDate[1] = intval($arDate[1]);
  $arDate[2] = intval($arDate[2]);

  //DebugMessage($arDate);
  $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $arDate[1], $arDate[0], $arDate[2]);

  $LicenseData->LicenseDate  = date('Ymd\TH:i:s', $ts);

}
```

My problem is, when I am using `var_dump($LicenseData->LicenseDate);` I am getting a different datetime value as output as string '20111104T00:00:00' (length=17) . solution is appreciated . Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up day and year in [`mktime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

Should be:

```
$ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $arDate[1], $arDate[2], $arDate[0]);
```

Comment: what is wrong with it ? $LicenseData->LicExpirDate = "12.12.2016"; if (strlen($LicenseData->LicExpirDate) > 0) { $arDate = explode(".", $LicenseData->LicExpirDate); $arDate[0] = intval($arDate[0]); $arDate[1] = intval($arDate[1]); $arDate[2] = intval($arDate[2]); //DebugMessage($arDate); $ts = mktime(0, 0, 0, $arDate[1], $arDate[2], $arDate[0]); $LicenseData->LicExpirDate = date('Ymd\TH:i:s', $ts); }

Comment: That's different code than what you state in your question.